# bash/readline: How to enable *-expansion on <TAB>?

Tags: bash, debian, readline

After switching from Ubuntu 20.04 to Debian 11 I noticed that typing, for example

```
$ rm *.db<TAB>
```

no longer attempts to expand `*.db`. What used to happen (on Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier versions) was that hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> would replace `*` if there was one possible match, or if multiple matches existed, they'd be shown.

Is there any way to enable this?